# Javaserver Faces javax.el.methodnotfoundexception when use commandButton

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have page that contains the following code:

```
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h:graphicImage id="logo" alt="pir logo" url="/images/logo.png" />
    <h1>Wybrane produkty:</h1>
    <h:dataTable value="#{selectedItemBean.list}" var="l"
        styleClass="order-table" headerClass="order-table-header"
        rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                        Symbol
                    </f:facet>
                        #{l.symbol}
                </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                        Opis
                    </f:facet>
                        #{l.opis}
                </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                        Cena
                    </f:facet>
                        #{l.cena}
                </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <input value="Popraw" type="button" onclick="history.go(-1)" />
    <h:commandButton value="Print" action="#{selectedItemBean.printPDF}" />
</h:form>
```

when i try execute commandbutton i got the following exception:

```
SEVERE: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: pl.com.pir.beans.SelectedItemBean@7cd2da43.printPDF()
```

I wonder what I'm doing wrong?

Bean source:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
    public class SelectedItemBean implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();

        public SelectedItemBean() {}

        //................. SOME CODE

        public void printPDF() {
            PrintToPDF pdf = new PrintToPDF();
            try {
            pdf.createPdf("", list);
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            } catch(DocumentException de) {
                de.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //................. SOME CODE

    }
```

datatable in result.xhtml is done properly, i have read much about this exception, but I have not found a solution.

Comment: @PremGenError by the use of the annotations, this is a JSF 2 question.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Try to clean, rebuild and redeploy your project and test again.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an old compiled version of SelectedItemBean  lying around somewhere?

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez the `actionListener` would throw the same error too. Even if it worked, OP should change the method to receive an `ActionEvent event` parameter.

Comment: i tried to rebuild and clean project, and problem still occur